# Need to count down a certain amount of time and present a refresh button to the user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, countdown

I have an MVC application that I need to countdown a certain number of time (The user will not see this time).  At the end of this period of time, the user will be presented a button.  This button will refresh the page.

I guess I could start by creating a

```
    <input id="bID" name="bID" visible="false"/>
```

Button.  But I need a countdown for that period of time and then I can set the visible to true.  How can I do that?
I have was using this tool countdown countdown...

Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript. When your page loads, you can fire the timer and it will display your button to the user.

```
setTimeout(function(){/* set visible to true here... */}, delay);
```

Comment: I guess I am showing my rookie colors here, but I am not even sure if that above would make my button invisible.  I ran it in JsFiddle and it doesn't make it invisible.  How do I make buttons invisible, and visible again?

Comment: You can safely replace visible="false" with style="display:none;". If you use jQuery, you can simply call $('#bID').css('display','block'); to show the button.  setTimeout(function(){ $('#bID').css('display','block'); }, 1000); // in ~1000ms function will fire and change css.

Comment: It's got to be easier than that?

Comment: Well, this isn't hard at all. You need to perform a time delayed action. First thing you need is to set its initial non visible state: <input id="bID" name="bID" style="display:none;"/>. At this stage, this button will not be visible. If you use jquery, you can add following code: $(document).ready(function(){  setTimeout(function(){ $('#bID').css('display','block'); } , 2000);  });     Where 2000 is ~ 2 seconds delay. I hope this is more clear. I don't know if you can have it more simple than this.